# Get Restkit to use sqlite database rather than download again from the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am basically trying to make my app more efficient by introducing an sqlite database rather than downloading the data each time. I have not included a default sqlite file with prepopulated information, I want the app to download it once with the idea being that the user can choose when to update.

Right now I believe I have the sqlite database in place, I have checked it in the simulator and the data has been downloaded and mapped correctly. In my view I am doing a getObjectsAtPath. What I want to do is tell the app to use what I have already got in the sqlite database rather than re-downloading the same data.

In my AppDelegate.m I did

```
NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Blogs.sqlite"];
// I added the following line in an attempt to get the app to use the sqlite file already created
NSString *seedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Blogs" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:seedPath withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Set the default store shared instance
[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

In my ViewController I have

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/post" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    // Do stuff with fetchedResultsController
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Show some errors
}];

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post"     inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"post_title" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];    
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Location"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

If there is any more relevant code I should post or more detail I can add to the question please ask. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a different approach. Abstract your view controllers away from getting new data (other than hosting the button that the user uses to trigger getting new data). Instead, have the view controllers observe the MOC to get their data and update the UI when that data changes (an FRC is handy for this - `NSFetchedResultsController`).

RestKit is not based around trying to guess if you want local results or remote results. It goes and gets remote results when you tell it you want them, maps them and stores them for you to use locally.

Now, you can trigger a request for the data when the app is first loaded (after install). After that, you only make a request when the user taps a button to refresh. In either case, your view controllers are just observing the MOC and display any new data that arrives.

Comment: I ended up abstracting away the retrieval of data as suggested. For future people stumbling upon this question, NSNotifications when the data is retrieved did the trick. And then the view controller uses the NSFetchedResultsController to display data. Cheers.